# Изменение размеров объекта при изменении размеров окна в JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Изучаю FXML и появилась проблема: мне нужно чтобы при изменении размеров окна, менялся и размер кнопки. Но я не могу это сделать, ведь отслеживать размеры окна я могу только из главного класа, а взаимодействовать с кнопкой только из контроллера. К примеру:

Main.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("Interface.fxml")));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Hello, FXML!");
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.show();
        stage.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Controller.java:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Button btn;

    private int clicks = 0;

    @FXML
    private void click(ActionEvent event) {
        btn.setText("Clicks: "+(++clicks));
    }
}
```

Interface.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane fx:id="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.company.Controller">
    <Button prefWidth="350" prefHeight="250" text="Click" onAction="#click" fx:id="btn" />
</StackPane>
```

Можно ли это как-то реализовать вместе с FXML?

Comment: В инициализации контроллера из любого элемента можно получить сцену, в которой он находится. Далее к свойствам ширины и высоты можно добавить `scene.widthProperty().addListener` и там рассчитать и установить новые размеры для кнопки

Comment: Точно, спасибо.